# How to calculate relevance score?

Tags: python, relevance

I am trying to calculate relevance score using a review from a json file. Every time I tried to run my code, it will only say "indirect" for output.
What am I doing wrong?

My code is below:

```
import joblib, requests, json, sklearn.metrics, sklearn.model_selection, sklearn.tree, time, math, textblob

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

response = requests.get("https://appliance_reviews.json")

if response:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    
    unique = []
    word = []
    for line in data:
        #print(line)
        
        review = line["Review"]
        blob = textblob.TextBlob(review)
        
        for word in blob.words:
            
            if word.lower() not in unique:
                unique.append(word.lower())
   
    for word in unique:
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        d = 0
       
        for line in data:
           
            review = line["Review"]
            safety = line["Safety hazard"]
           
            if word in review.lower() and safety == 1:
                a += 1
            if word in review.lower() and safety == 0:
                b += 1
            if word in review.lower() and safety == 1:
                c += 1
            if word in review.lower() and safety == 0:
                d += 1
        
        try:
            rel_score = (math.sqrt(a + b + c + d) * ((a + d) - (c * b))) / math.sqrt((a + b) * (c + d))
        except:

            rel_score = 0
            
        if rel_score >= 4000:
            score.append(word)
    print(word)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your posted code is not minimal: you've imported 10 packages to support a relevance classification.  You haven't traced the intermediate results, and you've made it hard for us to do so by using generic variable names and not explaining your algorithm.

Comment: How many words would you expect to score in total? An idea of the scale of the action might lead to different choices.

Answer (score 0):

`word` would just be the last entry in `unique` at the time you print it on the last line of code given, regardless of its scoring. You've just exited a `for` loop where `word` was the iterating variable.

Are you sure that you didn't want to print `score`, which seems to be intended to accumulate high-scoring words from `unique`?

Also I think your scoring is broken. For example as coded, `a` and `c` are always equal, as are `b` and `d`. "carpet" would affect the score of both "car", "pet" and indeed "carp".

As [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185) mentions in comments, your bland choice of variable names makes understanding the purpose of the code difficult.